# "ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification"

Tags: oracle, linked-server

I am trying to execute this query against Oracle linked server, and getting the following error, which I know that my query is malformed, but I couldn't figure out where and how.

```
DECLARE @CREDIT_CUST_SQL NVARCHAR(1000) = NULL;
SET @CREDIT_CUST_SQL = 'SELECT 
                           cu.[ST_CD]
                          ,cu.[SRT_CD]
                          ,cu.[TITLE]
                          ,cu.[FNAME]
                          ,cu.[INIT]
                          ,cu.[LNAME]
                          ,cu.[ADDR1]
                          ,cu.[ADDR2]
                          ,cu.[CITY]
                          ,cu.[COUNTRY]
                          ,cu.[ZIP_CD]
                          ,cu.[HOME_PHONE]
                          ,cu.[BUS_PHONE]
                          ,cu.[EXT]
                        FROM [AR].[CUST] cu, 
                             [CUSTOM].[CUST_OTHER] co, 
                             [AR].[CUST_CR] cc
                        WHERE cu.CUST_CD = co.CUST_CD 
                            AND cu.CUST_CD = cc.CUST_CD
                            AND cu.DOB IS NOT NULL'



EXECUTE (@CREDIT_CUST_SQL) AT LIVE_BD;
```

And I get this error,

> "ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification"

Any idea why is happening. Thanks.

Comment: you should also probably use explict joins ie. FROM Cust cu INNER JOIN Cust_Other co on cu.Cust_CD = co.Cust_CD ..... instead of the cartestian joins you are using ie. FROM cust, cust_other

Comment: @Leslie, the joins are being done in the where clause. This is not a cartesian join.

Comment: @Dcookie - by having the FROM clause refernce 2 tables and doing the condition in the where is the definition of a cartesian join:        A Cartesian join is when you join every row of one table to every row of another table. 
You can also get one by joining every row of a table to every row of itself.
Select *
From Film_Table, Director_Film_Table;                                                                  http://www.fluffycat.com/SQL/Cartesian-Joins/

Comment: @Leslie, mixing inner join conditions and filters in the where clause (aka performing joins in the where clause) was a common practice before sql-92 standard is supported by major databases, lot's of applications contains joins like this, and engines are designed to treat this as a inner or even outer join and not a full Cartesian product.  I know people writing new queries this way and I think engines will continue supporting this a long time.  Of course, a query is easier to read using proper sql-92 syntax to express join conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks like SQL Server

Do not use the brackets (<kbd>[</kbd> <kbd>]</kbd>) to quote the column names, just leave it as is for the capitalized valid identifiers or use the (sql standard) double quotes to the non valid identifiers or non capitalized ones.

Like this:

```
SELECT 
                       cu.ST_CD
                      ,cu.SRT_CD
                      ,cu.TITLE
                      ,cu.FNAME
                      ,cu.INIT
                      ,cu.LNAME
                      ,cu.ADDR1
                      ,cu.ADDR2
                      ,cu.CITY
                      ,cu.COUNTRY
                      ,cu.ZIP_CD
                      ,cu.HOME_PHONE
                      ,cu.BUS_PHONE
                      ,cu.EXT
                    FROM AR.CUST cu, 
                         CUSTOM.CUST_OTHER co, 
                         AR.CUST_CR cc
                    WHERE cu.CUST_CD = co.CUST_CD 
                        AND cu.CUST_CD = cc.CUST_CD
                        AND cu.DOB IS NOT NULL
```